# ReactJS high memory usage when re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-redux

I've working on a ReactJS+Redux project which basically pulls some data (hundreds/thousands or items) from an API and renders them in the UI.

The problem that I'm having is that after 20-30 actions and multiple list rerenders, the memory usage goes up to 1GB and I cannot figure out why.

I've tried to debug this myself but i am really new to debuging memory leaks in frontend code. What I did notice is that the number of nodes double with each list re-render.

What i've been doing:

- Load the tool and render the full list of items (GET API call)
- Add a new item to the list (POST API call)
- Re-render the list (retrieve it again from the API)
- Repeat about 10-20 times
- Memory usage goes up to 1GB (having started with 120mb)

I'm running the code in production with no debug options and no browser plugins.

```
const render  = Component => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <AppContainer>
                        <Component />
                    </AppContainer>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        ),
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
}

let store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk))

render(App)
```

reducer for the list of items

```
import {
    FETCH_ITEMSLIST_BEGIN,
    FETCH_ITEMSLIST_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_ITEMSLIST_FAILURE,
} from '../actions/itemsList'

const initialState = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
}

export default function itemsList(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_ITEMSLIST_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            }

        case FETCH_ITEMSLIST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                data: action.data
            }

        case FETCH_ITEMSLIST_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: 'ERROR: ' + action.data + ' dispatched by: ' + action.type,
                data: []
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

reducer for deleting an item

```
import {
    ITEM_DELETE_RESET,
    ITEM_DELETE_BEGIN,
    ITEM_DELETE_SUCCESS,
    ITEM_DELETE_FAILURE,
    ITEM_DELETE_DISPLAY_CONFIRMATION,
    ITEM_DELETE_HIDE_CONFIRMATION
} from '../actions/itemDelete'

import { FETCH_ITEMSLIST_SUCCESS } from '../actions/itemsList'
import { UPDATE_ITEM_SELECTED } from '../actions/selectedItem'
import { TAB_PANNEL_SWITCHED } from '../actions/itemDetailsPanel'

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    success: false,
    itemId: null,
    displayConfirmation: false
}

export default function itemDelete(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ITEM_DELETE_RESET:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: false,
                success: false,
                displayConfirmation: false
            }
        case ITEM_DELETE_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: false,
                success: false,
                displayConfirmation: false
            }

        case ITEM_DELETE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: false,
                success: action.response,
                displayConfirmation: false

            }

        case ITEM_DELETE_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.response,
                success: false,
                displayConfirmation: false

            }

        case FETCH_ITEMSLIST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: false,
                success: false,
                displayConfirmation: false
            }

        case ITEM_DELETE_DISPLAY_CONFIRMATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                displayConfirmation: true
            }

        case ITEM_DELETE_HIDE_CONFIRMATION:
        case UPDATE_ITEM_SELECTED:
        case TAB_PANNEL_SWITCHED:
            return {
                ...state,
                displayConfirmation: false
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

[image: chrome performance]
Later edit:
What I'm doing to test is click on an item in a list which opens up a side panel and changes the page URL. I then close the side panel thus changing the URL back. I thought this might be relevant

Comment: Could it be that the old state is not getting garbage collected? Maybe you somehow copy a reference to the previous state embedded in the new in your reducer? It's hard to tell without you sharing your code. For example the reducer and where you configure the redux store.

Comment: As said above, you are probably not unreferencing the old datas so it's still in the memory and not garbage collected.

Comment: Was thinking that the GC is not doing it's job for some reason. Let me add more information to the question above. I cannot share all the code because I don't own it.